# Is there a way to append React.createElement to existing div?

Tags: reactjs

With socket.io, I am trying to create a live chat app, for every message, I want to append a message to the messagesContainer. However when appending the child to the messagesContainer the result keeps being "[Object Object]"

code:

```html
socket.on("chat-message", data => {
  const newMessage = React.createElement('div', {className: "messages"}, [
    React.createElement('div', {className: "usernamepic"}, [
      React.createElement('img', {src: data.pic, className: "usernamepicsrc"},      null),
    ]),
    React.createElement('div', {className: "actualmessages"}, [
      React.createElement('div', {className: "authorname"}, data.name),
      React.createElement('div', {className: "messagetext"}, data.message),
    ]),

  ])
  const messageContainer = document.getElementById("actualchatmessages");
  messageContainer.append(newMessage);



})
```

Comment: This seems like an antipattern (ie the wrong way to go about this).  I would recommend an alternative approach in which the `socket.on` listener is setup in the `useEffect` and then when each message comes in it is added to the data model (something like `const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);`, and then the UI will load the messages when the data model is updated.  This would be easier, more idiomatic of React, and keep it in the React lifecycle.  Remember, generally if you are doing direct DOM querying and manipulation in React you might be on the wrong path.

Comment: you need to use ReactDOM.render method instead of append dom element

Comment: ```import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <NewMessage />,
  document.getElementById('actualchatmessages')
);
```
and your component must start with uppercase letter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a React element as a native HTML element, you would first need to turn it into actual HTML by using `renderToString` from `react-dom`

Something like this:

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

socket.on("chat-message", (data) => {
  const newMessage = React.createElement("div", { className: "messages" }, [
    React.createElement("div", { className: "usernamepic" }, [
      React.createElement(
        "img",
        { src: data.pic, className: "usernamepicsrc" },
        null
      ),
    ]),
    React.createElement("div", { className: "actualmessages" }, [
      React.createElement("div", { className: "authorname" }, data.name),
      React.createElement("div", { className: "messagetext" }, data.message),
    ]),
  ]);

  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerHTML = renderToString(newMessage);

  const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#actualchatmessages");
  messageContainer.append(el.firstChild);
});
```